# Cannot see theme in my search

Tags: themes

I have just installed a fresh Wordpress on my own One.com webspace. I would like to install the '[Hemingway Rewritten](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/hemingway-rewritten/)' theme, but the search engine within my Wordpress does not appear to list this theme. Instead, a search for 'hemingway' returns an apparently older version of a similar theme, called '[Hemingway](https://wordpress.org/themes/hemingway)'.

Why can I not see the newer version of the theme? I installed Wordpress as a fresh installation this morning, so I can't see any reason why I would have received an outdated version of the Wordpress architecture (I am on 4.0).

Comment: 'hemigway-rewritten' is a ***.com*** theme, as your link to it clearly shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes (and plugins for that matter) in the wordpress respitory are uploaded to wordpress.org by their respective authors. These themes and plugins are not written or updated or maintainted by the Wordpress team who are responsible for Wordpress core.

These plugin and theme authors are normal members of the public like you and me. It is their responsibilty to keep their plugins and themes up to date etc.

What you are experiencing are most probably that the theme authour has created this version of his theme only for wordpress.com hosted sites and not for self hosted sites, and it will not be at all made available to self hosted sites. You have to remember, wordpress.com has its own respitory diffirent from wordpress.org

You will need to contact the author for any further details regarding this matter